# How do I specify what to limit in an includes activerecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I have

```
Shop.includes(:opening_times)
              .where("opening_times.day =?", Time.now.wday)
              .where("opening_times.opens > ?", @now)
              .order("opening_times.opens")
              .references(:opening_times)
              .limit(12)
```

Whenever it hits a shop with two opening times, it returns only 11 shops. I guess it's limiting to 12 opening_times instead of 12 shops. How can I specify that I want to limit 12 shops, not 12 opening_times?

Strangely, this only happens when I order by opening times. If I take away the `.order("opening_times.opens")`, it returns 12 shops.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of your shop has 2 opening_times records, and your SQL engine return them both.

Try adding distinct like this: `Shop.distinct.includes(:opening_times).where...`

Comment: I don't understand why, but when I do that it says `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT" LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT DISTINCT`. Somehow it's showing DISTINCT twice. I'm so confused.